# Prove the topology $\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{(-\infty, c) | c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is Tychonoff

Tags: general-topology

Problem 14 in Chapter 11 of Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis is this:

Consider the set of real numbers with the topology consisting of the empty-set and the sets of the form $(-\infty, c), c \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that this space is Tychonoff but not Hausdorff.

So I need to show that if $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u < v$, then there exists a neighborhood of $u$ that does not contain $v$ and a neighborhood of $v$ that does not contain $u$. WLOG suppose $u < v$. Then there is a real number $p$ such that $u < p < v$. So the open set $(-\infty, p)$ is a neighborhood of $u$ that doesn't contain $v$.

But how can I find a neighborhood of $v$ that doesn't contain $u$. A neighborhood of $v$ is an open set that contains $v$. But every open set is of the form $(-\infty, c)$. So every neighborhood of $v$ is a neighborhood of $u$. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Also, is $\mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{T}$? It must be because $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology. Does this require us to let $c$ take the extended real value $+\infty$?

Comment: Why do you need to show that if $u, b \in \Bbb{R}$ and $u<v$, then there exists a neighbourhood of $u$ that does not contain $v$ and a neighbourhood of $v$ that does not contain $u$?

Comment: Royden's defines a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ to have the Tychonoff propert if "For each two points $u$ and $v$ in $X$, there is a neighborhood of $u$ that does not contain $v$ and a neighborhood of $v$ that does not contain $u$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Complete Revision** (because I was clearly not thinking when I wrote the original answer)

That space is **not** Tikhonov (or completely regular). It is a $T_0$ space that is not Hausdorff, and every completely regular $T_0$-space is Hausdorff.

To see this, let $X$ be a completely regular $T_0$-space, and let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points of $X$. Without loss of generality there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$. Since $X$ is completely regular there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(z)=1$ for $z\in X\setminus U$. Now let

$$V=f^{-1}\left[0,\frac12\right)\quad\text{and}\quad W=f^{-1}\left(\frac12,1\right]\;.$$

Since $f$ is continuous, $V$ and $W$ are open in $X$, and clearly $V\cap W=\varnothing$. Finally, $x\in V$ and $y\in W$, so $V$ and $W$ are a Hausdorff separation of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: ? = (y-x)/(c-x)? So as $y \to x$, $f(y) \to 0$ and as $y \to c$, $f(y) \to 1$. Then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric and so a restriction of $f$ to this topology is also continuous. But now I wonder about the definition of the Tychonoff separation property on page 227 of Royden/Fitzpatrick.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, that linear interpolation is exactly what I had in mind. As for the terminology, some authors switch the terms. My usage is the more common one nowadays, but you do have to watch out for this.

Comment: Sorry for maybe a stupid question, but why does $f$ being continuous in Euclidean topology imply its continuity in $\mathcal{T}$? If $\mathcal{T}$ is smaller, then wouldn't there be some open sets whose preimage is not necessarily in $\mathcal{T}$ but yet in the Euclidean topology? Such as $f^{-1}]0,1[$?

Comment: @Thomas: Brain hiccup: for some reason I had $f$ going in the wrong direction when I wrote that addendum.

Comment: Hm, I agree with your intuition @ThomasE.; however, Royden says that "For a continuous mapping $f$ of a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$, by the definition of the subspace topology, the restriction of $f$ to a subspace of $X$ is also continuous." The proof is not given. Have I misunderstood this statement? It comes straight after the open set characterization of continuity. I tried to write a proof but the way I tried didn't work.

Comment: @AlexOlssen. Subspaces are a different thing. In this case we have two different topologies for $\mathbb{R}$ and know a strict inclusion between them. Subspace is a subset with the subspace topology. And what Royden says is true, that a continuous function restricted to a subspace is always continuous. It is an easy application of the definitions.

Comment: @Alex: You’ve misunderstood it, I think, since it’s not relevant here: the topology $\mathcal{T}$ is not a subspace topology inherited from the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, but rather a coarser topology on $\Bbb R$. If $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a space, and $Y\subseteq X$, the subspace topology on $Y$ is $\{U\cap Y:U\in\tau\}$.

Comment: @Alex: You’re welcome!

Comment: One more question though. If we have the linear interpolation between $x$ and $c$, then $f^{-1}]0,1[=]x,c[\notin\mathcal{T}$. Are you sure it is possible to make $f$ continuous in $\mathcal{T}$?

Comment: @Thomas: Argh. I really need to wake up. You are of course right. The linear interpolation is not continuous. What’s wanted is the indicator function of $F$, which means that I need to ping Alex. Many thanks for catching that bit of idiocy on my part.

Comment: @Alex: My profound apologies: I must have been asleep earlier. No, the linear interpolation doesn’t work, because it’s not continuous: however, replacing the question mark by $0$ does. Then for any open $U\subseteq[0,1]$ you have $f^{-1}[U]=\varnothing$ if $U\subseteq(0,1)$, $f^{-1}[U]=(\leftarrow,c)$ if $0\in U\subseteq[0,1)$, and $f^{-1}[U]=\Bbb R$ if $0,1\in U$. All of these are $\mathcal{T}$-open.

Comment: How about $f^{-1}(0,1]$? :)

Comment: @Thomas: *sigh* I let myself be blinded by the source of the problem. The result is simply false. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. It looks good now.

Comment: @Thomas: I just **really** wish that I’d woken up before Alex accepted it!